# Converting React class with "static get defaultProps()" to functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As I make code changes to existing React class components I've been converting them to functional components with hooks. We have come components with defaultProps that have labels that are 18n. The values in the i18n() function are loaded with a REST call so they can't be called when the file loads so we have to do this to load them when the instance is created:

```
  static get defaultProps() {
    return {
      open: false,
      title: i18n('confirm.title'),
      message: i18n('confirm.message'),
      confirmButtonText: i18n('confirm.confirmBtn'),
      cancelButtonText: i18n('confirm.cancelBtn'),
      callback: noop
    };
  }
```

Obviously converting this scenario to a functional component and doing this doesn't work because values for i18n() aren't available yet.

```
Confirm.defaultProps = {
  open: false,
  title: i18n('confirm.title'),
  message: i18n('confirm.message'),
  confirmButtonText: i18n('confirm.confirmBtn'),
  cancelButtonText: i18n('confirm.cancelBtn'),
  callback: noop
};
```

Any ideas on how to convert these class components to functional where i18n() needs called when the component is created?

Comment: why are you using props for some i18n messages?

Comment: you should not use an async function/a function which depends on async values inside defaultProps anyway. I would replace i18n with a component which renders the message based on the message key instead (and which can make sure the messages are loaded before rendering them).

Comment: I put the answers in the comment below - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60514248/6646367

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using default props in functional components will be deprecated (https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/16210). You should see a warning when you use them actually.

You can either try and not use props for properties you need i18n for, or use those values as fallback in case the prop is undefined:

e.g.

```
<div>{props.title || i18n('confirm.title')}</div>
```

The alternative for functional components is ES6 default params using destructuring - but I'm not sure that will help in your case.

```
function MyComponent({title = i18n('confirm.title')}) {
...
}
```

Is your i18n function asynchronous? I that case I'd say you should replace it with a component which renders the message, because those might not be available even when you render initially (even if in most cases they are).

LE: here is a relevant discussion on this topic: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/1009

Comment: My i18n function is synchronous and just returns the value from a JSON structure which is loaded from a REST call when the app initializes. I decided to go with the ES6 default params using destructuring and it works great except the eslint rule `react/require-default-props` isn't happy. What is recommended in this case - disable it for the file or is there another rule to use?

Comment: Unfortunately that rule doesn't support ES6 default arguments. You can either disable it for that file or disable is for all functional components (I'd only disable it for that file for now). Here are more details about the rule: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/require-default-props.md and a discussion about this issue: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/1009

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Object.defineProperty(Confirm, 'defaultProps', { 
  get() {
    return {
      open: false,
      title: i18n('confirm.title'),
      message: i18n('confirm.message'),
      confirmButtonText: i18n('confirm.confirmBtn'),
      cancelButtonText: i18n('confirm.cancelBtn'),
      callback: noop
    }; 
  },
  enumerable: true 
});
```

This will allow you a getter function for the property like you've got in the class version of the code.